# Replacing a HTML tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, string

Ok so after an AJAX Get request 'success' is called and the string 'data' is passed, which contains the html of the site requested. Now I want to extract everything in the `<body>` tag of the current site and replace it with everything in the `<body>` tag that's stored in the data string. How is this done?

I tried `var b = $(data).find('body');` and then `.replaceWith(b)` but `b` is apparently an object.

Thanks for your help!

Edit; Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "managefiles.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
          ...
        }
     });
```

Comment: You should consider modifying the server-side script to return only the data you need instead of extracting it client-side.

Comment: what does your jQuery `ajax()` call look like? What is your `dataType`?

Comment: If you can't modify the HTML coming from the source, I updated my answer to give perhaps a little safer approach than appending the entire HTML document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that you need to do is replace the `html()` of the `body` tag

```
$("body").html($(data).find("body"));
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Doing `.find("body")` will likely not work in most browsers (assuming an entire HTML document was sent to the jQuery object).

Comment: (gasp!) can you tell me what your "data" object looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Append it to `body`

```
$("body").empty(); // clear
b.appendTo("body"); // append new
```

- [jQuery appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Answer (score 2):

$('body').html(data);

Answer (score 2):

This can be a little tricky because browsers behave differently in the situation where you pass an entire HTML document into a jQuery object.

Depending on which browser you're using, some tags (including `<body>` in some cases) will be stripped away.

While you could just add the entire HTML document to the current `<body>` and hope that the browser does the right thing, it would be better to have your server return only the content you actually want.

---

**EDIT:** If you can't modify the HTML coming from the source, you could try this in order to make it a little safer:

```
var $data = $(data);
var $contents;

if( $data.filter('body').length ) {
  $contents = $data.filter('body').contents();
} else if( $data.find('body').length ) {
  $contents = $data.find('body').contents();
} else {
  $contents = $data;
}

$(document.body).empty().append( $contents );
```

Comment: You are right. Neither mine, nor other's answers are working in Opera for me.